# Passing custom distance matrix to T_Coffee

Tags: sequence-alignment, covid-19

I am passing a custom distance matrix to T_Coffee (written in C), as per the docs, but can't seem to get it to work.

The documentation says to pass a matrix like this using BLAST format
https://tcoffee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcoffee_technical_documentation.html#blast-format-recommended

```
# BLAST_MATRIX FORMAT
# ALPHABET=AGCT
A G C T
A 0 1 2 3
G 0 2 3 4
C 1 1 2 3
...
```

I've tried all combinations (with and without the leading # comments, and with and without the trailing) ..., but no matter what I keep getting this error:

> Parsing_error when reading blast_matrix doolittle: A C 0

Here, my distance matrix file is titled doolittle because it is the difference between the hydropathy indices of amino acids based on the Kyte-Doolittle scale * 10 to make them all integers. I've pasted the full matrix below.

I am calling the command from linux 18.08 ubuntu terminal (although I've tried most other combinations.)

```
t_coffee -in=rhomboids.fasta -matrix doolittle
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

doolittle

```
# BLAST_MATRIX FORMAT
# ALPHABET=ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY
A C D E F G H I K L M N P Q R S T V W Y
A 0 7 53 53 10 22 50 27 57 20 1 53 34 53 58 26 25 24 27 31
C 7 0 60 60 3 29 57 20 64 13 6 60 41 60 65 33 32 17 34 38
D 53 60 0 0 63 31 3 80 4 73 54 0 19 0 5 27 28 77 26 22
E 53 60 0 0 63 31 3 80 4 73 54 0 19 0 5 27 28 77 26 22
F 10 3 63 63 0 32 60 17 67 10 9 63 44 63 68 36 35 14 37 41
G 22 29 31 31 32 0 28 49 35 42 23 31 12 31 36 4 3 46 5 9
H 50 57 3 3 60 28 0 77 7 70 51 3 16 3 8 24 25 74 23 19
I 27 20 80 80 17 49 77 0 84 7 26 80 61 80 85 53 52 3 54 58
K 57 64 4 4 67 35 7 84 0 77 58 4 23 4 1 31 32 81 30 26
L 20 13 73 73 10 42 70 7 77 0 19 73 54 73 78 46 45 4 47 51
M 1 6 54 54 9 23 51 26 58 19 0 54 35 54 59 27 26 23 28 32
N 53 60 0 0 63 31 3 80 4 73 54 0 19 0 5 27 28 77 26 22
P 34 41 19 19 44 12 16 61 23 54 35 19 0 19 24 8 9 58 7 3
Q 53 60 0 0 63 31 3 80 4 73 54 0 19 0 5 27 28 77 26 22
R 58 65 5 5 68 36 8 85 1 78 59 5 24 5 0 32 33 82 31 27
S 26 33 27 27 36 4 24 53 31 46 27 27 8 27 32 0 1 50 1 5
T 25 32 28 28 35 3 25 52 32 45 26 28 9 28 33 1 0 49 2 6
V 24 17 77 77 14 46 74 3 81 4 23 77 58 77 82 50 49 0 51 55
W 27 34 26 26 37 5 23 54 30 47 28 26 7 26 31 1 2 51 0 4
Y 31 38 22 22 41 9 19 58 26 51 32 22 3 22 27 5 6 55 4 0
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I am only able to give you non specific advice, but have you tried the most recent version of t-coffee? Which version are you using? Maybe you could try a smaller sized matrix to test (like a 4x4). You could also submit an issue on their github.

Comment: Could this be a simple line ending issue? Are you using Windows to generate the file by any chance?

Comment: @terdon I am using Ubuntu, but good suggestion. Definitely been stung by the \r\n windows bug/feature before.

Answer (score 3):

So I didn't find an answer,but I did find a way around if it anyone else has this problem. It does involve modifying the source code, but even if you don't understand c (I barely do) its still easy to do.

1) Download source code from github 
https://github.com/cbcrg/tcoffee
Source code is here, view the dependency list - you will need all these libraries to compile the code for the change to take effect.

2) Add your custom matrix to source code.
Search `matrices.h`. In this version it is `t_coffee/lib/matrices.h`
You will see how they are defining their default matrices. Just add your matrix with the same format and give it a name. For example:

```
int customMT[]={
  4,
  0,  5,
 -3, -2, 17,
  0,  5, -3,  9,
  0,  0,  1,  1,  6,
 -2, -3, -3, -5, -4, 10,
  0,  0, -4, -1, -2, -3,  8,
 -2, -2, -5, -2,  0, -3, -3, 14,
  0, -2, -2, -4, -3,  0, -1, -2,  6,
  0,  0, -3,  0,  2, -1, -1, -2, -2,  4,
 -1, -1,  0, -1, -1,  2, -2, -1,  2, -2,  4,
  1, -2, -2, -3, -1, -2, -2,  2,  1,  2,  2,  6,
  0,  4, -1,  1, -1, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0, -2,  0,  8,
 -1, -2, -3, -1,  1, -4, -1,  1, -3,  1, -3, -4, -3, 11,
  1, -1, -2, -1,  2, -3, -2,  0, -2,  0, -2, -1, -1,  0,  8,
 -1, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, -3,  1, -2,  0, -2, -1,  3,  8,
  1,  0, -2,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1, -1,  0, -2, -2,  0, -1, -1, -1,  4,
  1,  0, -2, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -3,  2,  5,
  1, -2, -2, -2, -3,  1, -3, -3,  4, -2,  1,  0, -2, -4, -3, -1, -1,  1,  5,
 -5, -5, -2, -4, -1,  1,  1, -5, -3, -2, -2, -3, -7, -3, -1,  0, -3, -5, -3, 20,
  0, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -2, -1,
 -4, -3, -6, -1, -2,  3, -3,  0, -1, -1,  3, -1, -4, -2, -1,  0, -2, -1,  1,  5, -1,  9,
  0,  0,  0,  0,  5, -4, -2,  0, -3,  1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  4,  0, -1, -1, -3, -1,  0, -2,  4};
```

Then, search for file `tcoffee/lib/io_lib/io_func.c` Find the function

```
int ** read_matrices( char *mat_name_in)
```

You will see a long list of if else clauses, add the name of your custom matrix using the same pattern as they do.

```
/*Read Header Matrices*/
if (strm(mat_name, "pam250mt"))vector=pam250mt;
else if (strm(mat_name, "idmat"))vector=idmat;
else if (strm(mat_name, "dna_idmat"))vector=idmat;

/*add custom matrix here*/
else if (strm(mat_name, "customMT"))vector=customMT;
```

3) Save the files, move into tcoffee/src/. Rebuild the files using the make file as described on the github installation. It is here you need make, g++, perl, and whatever else on the list as dependencies

```
make t_coffee
```

4) Now, align your file! The only thing here is to use the t_coffee of the source code you just edited, and not t_coffee that might already be on your path. So change t_coffee/src/t_coffee to whatever the relative path to this folder is.

```
tcoffee/src/t_coffee rhomboids.fasta -matrix customMT
```

And that's it!

Comment: Its a great question and presentation of the solution. It is an old last resort way of doing it, change the matrix and then re-compile. Reading the parsing code is the underlying issue. The only thing I would have suggested is get it working with the sample data first. It is a complicated table and if the parsing is sub-optimal and table not perfect it can trip the code. It only takes one part of the matrix to be missed and the whole thing falls over

Comment: Personally what I think has happened is the custom DNA matrix is probably heavily beta tested but the protein matrix much less so and I think thats what is being encountered here. Just to finally mention its also a good use of the custom distance matrix and interesting approach.